# List view throwing TypeError

Tags: react-admin

**What you were expecting:**
Just went through the tutorial (successfully) and tried to modify code to use my API. List view is not showing data and console has error.

I was able to add the API call for login and on the list view I can see my API is successfully called.

**What happened instead:**
Page shows title and "No results found"

Console error

```
index.js:2178 uncaught at handleFetch TypeError: newRecords.map is not a function
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:69772:52
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:69828:24
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:69917:40
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at ./node_modules/ra-core/lib/reducer/admin/resource/index.js.exports.default (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:69914:30)
    at combination (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134671:29)
    at combination (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134671:29)
    at resettableAppReducer (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:63329:16)
    at dispatch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134907:22)
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:119507:18
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:132848:22
    at dispatch (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134462:18)
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134352:12
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:133375:52
    at exec (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134015:5)
    at flush (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134056:5)
    at asap (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134029:5)
    at runPutEffect (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:133372:69)
    at runEffect (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:133321:307)
    at next (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:133201:9)
    at currCb (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:133274:7)
```

API Response Data from DevTools (Couldn't figure out how to format the data so it's a screen cap.)
[image: API Response]

API Response from Postman

```
{
"matches": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "status": "READY"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    }
]
```

}

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range 
Connection: keep-alive 
content-range: matches 0-5/5 
Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2018 16:33:12 GMT 
ETag: W/"a5-KZYtsf9f1aSutDA6i7vGzddXNZk" 
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Matches.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Edit, Create, Datagrid, ReferenceField, TextField, EditButton, DisabledInput, LongTextInput, ReferenceInput, SelectInput, SimpleForm, TextInput } from 'react-admin';

export const MatchList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="status" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

The tutorial was using the dummy api and I switched to ra-data-simple-rest. I had to make a few changes to my API output to match the format expected, so I'm guessing this might be the source of the problem, but the error is not helpful.

I originally had many columns and some were null, so I just left ID and Status. I do have 1 additional field returned in my results ("success": true). I removed that but got the same results.

**Other information:**

**Environment**

- React-admin version: 2.1.2
- Last version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable): N/A
- React version: 16.4.1
- Browser: Chrome/OSX
- Stack trace (in case of a JS error): above

Comment: Please show me yours data rest provider. Admin component should implement it in as dataProvider.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html

Comment: Are you asking what data provider I'm using? It's the ra-data-simple-rest. I'm trying to adjust my API output to match the results that it expects. 

import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your API is still not an immediate array. Either you alter your API a bit more or you alter your [dataProvider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html).

Option A: The server-side solution

Alter your API to output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "status": "DRAFT"
    },
    ...
]
```

You don't need the success property<sub>*</sub> if your leveraging HTTP statuses that can tell the client whether the server succeeded or not (200, 404, 500, etc). You also don't need the total property, since your API is already [telling](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) that to the client in the Content-range response header.

```
Content-range: matches 0-5/5
                           ^ total
```

Option B. The client-side solution

You're probably using some form of a Dataprovider which is a ra-something-client. It probably has a part that looks similar to this.

```
const convertHTTPResponseToREST = (response, type, resource, params) => {
    const { headers, json } = response;

    switch (type) {
        case GET_LIST:
        case GET_MANY_REFERENCE: {
            if (!headers.has('content-range')) {
                throw new Error(
                    'The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. ' +
                        'The PostgREST client expects responses for lists of resources to contain ' +
                        'this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. ' +
                        'If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the ' +
                        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?'
                );
            }
            return {
                data: json.slice(),
                total: parseInt(
                    headers
                        .get('content-range')
                        .split('/')
                        .pop(),
                    10
                ),
            };
        }
        case CREATE:
            return { data: { ...params.data, id: json.id } };
        case DELETE:
            return { data: {} };
        default:
            return { data: json };
    }
};
```

You can change a part of it to:

```
return {
    data: json.data.slice(),
    total: json.total || parseInt(
        headers
            .get('content-range')
            .split('/')
            .pop(),
        10
    ),
};
```

Or just:

```
return json;
```

<sub>* You may be used to sending the success property due to some Sencha/Ext JS clients. I know I was.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure why you say my output is not an array. fzaninotto on Github said the same thing. I'll add my current API output to original comment. Sorry for the confusing comment. Enter submitted when I wanted to get a new line.

Comment: My output has an array. Based on your comments, I made a few changes with same results: 1) Removed Total from output, 2) removed Status from output and changed data to matches. I'd really hoped #3 was my problem. The docs show "data" as the name before the array, but when I looked at the Simple example I could see it was the object name. It wasn't stated in the docs, but it appears that the data array name, the Resource name in App.js and the meta data in the Content Range header should all be the same. Is that right?

Comment: Read my words carefully. Your output is still not an array. It HAS an array in either your `data` or your `matches` property, but it still IS not an array. The array has to be the first thing that comes out of your API. That means the output starts with `[` and not `{`. Or change your dataprovider as stated in my answer.

Comment: Got it working. Sorry if I seemed like I wasn't reading your answer. I was just interpreting along with what I the docs said. At https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#response-format, it appears to say my API response should be an object with an array embedded.

Comment: I'm going to try and contribute to the project. I might be able to help improve the docs by looking at them through my dummy lens. Really glad to get this working as I'm excited to start using it.